# Debug an issue that occurs in Internet Explorer but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug some xsl code, which is causing a bug that occurs in Internet Explorer but not in another browser such as Chrome or FireFox. The error is basically when I make some changes on the webpage, such as adding new values into the fields, and I hit save it doesn't update those changes, but on another browser it does.

I have code like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="saveClicked(); return false;" class="{$defaultBtn}"><span>Save as Draft</span></a>
```

My question isn't really isn't why is does this not work, but how can I debug this code. Also if someone knows some common errors that happen when using IE that don't occur on Chrome/Firefox that would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you get any console JS errors?  does the value of `{$defaultBtn}` get rendered correctly?

Comment: F12 will bring up your Web Inspector in any browser above IE8. One common issue with IE is that console.log causes an error unless you have the inspector open. Could be as simple as that.

Comment: Check the browser mode. Is it loading in quirks mode or something like that? That's probably *the* most common issue. You can use the F12 tools to check this. The F12 tools are also useful for checking a lot of other things too.